# How to use curl commands with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, api

I need to use an API on my website that has its documentation written in CURL commands. Specifically, I would like to know how can I use a command like this on my React app.

```
curl -H token:"sfg999666t673t7t82" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "accept: application/json" -d '{"id":"3970a1b0-6e27-448a-adfc-0083db15b2fb", "tokens":{"design_token1":"Hi","design_token2":"Hello","design_token3":"World","subject_token1":"XYZ"}, "recipient":"james@sample.com"}' -X POST "https://domain.provider.com/mas/api/v1/mail/transaction"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rewrite it to fetch request

```js
fetch("https://domain.provider.com/mas/api/v1/mail/transaction", {
  body: "{\"id\":\"3970a1b0-6e27-448a-adfc-0083db15b2fb\", \"tokens\":{\"design_token1\":\"Hi\",\"design_token2\":\"Hello\",\"design_token3\":\"World\",\"subject_token1\":\"XYZ\"}, \"recipient\":\"james@sample.com\"}",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Token: "sfg999666t673t7t82"
  },
  method: "POST"
})
```

Comment: Also, there are some online resources where you can transform curl to fetch

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use js library like axios to perform request. Curl is just one of many options.. If you are looking for less programming way to do this you can use http clients like insomnia or postman and autogenerate code for your needs.

Comment: If they are using VSCode there I suggest they use Thunder Client plugin for basic API testing than having to install a whole different testing tool like Postman/Insomia etc. Unless they need to do specified testing.